# Can I retrieve the current telephone number?

Tags: android

I'm writing an app for Android (2.1+), and I'd like to use the telephone number of the current phone. Lots of googling brought me the following:

```
String number=(TelephonyManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE).getLine1Number();
```

That along with permission:  READ_PHONE_STATE.

My problem however is that it returns null. While searching, I noticed this question has been asked many times before and nearly in all of those questions it is said that the number simply isn't always available.

While testing I found that on my very own phone it gives me null. BUT another app (for example, [WhatsApp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WhatsApp)) was able to recognize my phone number).

So then I wonder, how did they do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I came up with another method to retrieve the telephone number (which in my case really is a absolute must-have).

1. The app must connect to a server.
2. The server gives the app a unique id and a telephone number.
3. The app sends a text message to the telephone number with the unique id.
4. The server (did I mention an SMS gateway should allow you to interpret the text message?) will see the number which sent the text message and the id that belongs to the app. This is stored in the database.
5. Now you'll have the means to retrieve the number using the identifier.

That's the basic idea.

Answer (score 3):

You can check this tutorial for [How to Get Own Mobile Number Programmatically](http://rdcworld-android.blogspot.in/2012/03/how-to-get-own-mobile-number.html)

Please read all the information I have written below tutorial there

> As I have read, so far some people have conflict about different
>   behavior of  output. There are reports that some SIMs cause this
>   method to return null.
>
> Because There is no guaranteed solution to this problem because the phone
>   number is not physically stored on all SIM-cards, or broadcasted from
>   the network to the phone. This is especially  true in some countries
>   which requires physical address verification, with number assignment
>   only happening afterwards.

Comment: I agree w/ this answer, why not just ask the user for their number when you can't find it?